# PL/SQL Compare XMLTypes

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I have a SQL table that I am using like a queue, with one of the column as a XMLType. What I'm trying to do with the table is creating a program to fetch a specific portion of the data, iterate through the table, read the information then delete the row after I'm done. I can't just wipe out the entire table after I'm done because not all of the data needs to be deleted.

My current solution:

```
   FOR xml_data FROM (SELECT xml_column from table_a) 
   LOOP
   -- Process the data
   ...

   --- Delete the row
   DELETE FROM table_a where xml_column = xml_data.xml_column;
   END LOOP;
```

However, I run into an issue with the delete portion which throws an error:

```
  Error report -
  ORA-22950: cannot ORDER objects with MAP or ORDER method
  ...
  Action: Define a MAP or ORDER method for the object type
```

Does anyone know what the solution for this is? I'm also open to other solutions to delete a row after iterating through it.

EDIT: Fix code

Comment: you need to post a [mcve]

Comment: I made some minor changes, but this is pretty much the minimum. My question pretty much boils down to 'how do you compare XMLTypes?'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Large or complex objects cannot be trivially compared with the equals sign.  Oracle is trying to save you here, because comparing huge objects could cause performance problems, and there are different ways to compare XML.  The error message `ORA-22950` is telling you that you *could* compare the objects if you built a specific comparison function.

But in this case there is no need to directly compare XML.  If you're looping through the rows in the table it's much faster to identify the rows by the `ROWID`, which is a physical pointer to the location of the row.

```
begin
    for xml_data in (select rowid, xml_column from table_a)
    loop
        -- Process the data
        -- ...

        delete from table_a where rowid = xml_data.rowid;
    end loop;
end;
/
```